# array/list as command line argument in roslaunch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am drawing some points inside rviz. I want to pass these points as command line argument to roslaunch file. In other word, I looking for a way to enter command like below-

```
roslaunch render_points renderer.launch points:=[x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2], [x3, y3, z3], [x4, y4, z4]
```

After this command, I should be able to get these points back inside python in similar way such as

```
points = rospy.get_param("~points", None)
# where points[0] is [x1, y1, z1] and points[1] is [x2, y2, z2] and so on..
```

I am not sure, whether it is possible or not. If not, please suggest some workaround to do the same.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245781/array/list-as-command-line-argument-in-roslaunch-file/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2016-10-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can achieve what you want with passing points as string of arrays to the launch file.

For roslaunch args, see [reference](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/arg)

My approach would be something like this:

```
$ roslaunch render_points array.launch points:="[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23], [31, 32, 33], [41, 42, 43]"
```

##### list_points.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy

if __name__=="__main__":
    rospy.init_node("list_points")
    points = rospy.get_param("~points", None)
    points = [[int(x.strip(' ')) for x in ss.lstrip(' [,').split(', ')] for ss in points.rstrip(']').split(']')]
    print(points[0])
```

##### renderer.launch

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
    <arg name="points" doc="description for this arg"/>
    <node pkg="render_points" type="list_points.py" name="list_points" output="screen">
        <param name="points" value="$(arg points)"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [abrzozowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28240/abrzozowski/) with karma: 290 on 2016-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2016-10-15**:
Seems acceptable. Passing arguments as string is more flexible in this case. Thanks a lot. Appreciate it.